# How do I fix references in an MVC C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am an intern at a company and one month in my mentor left. He was building a site that I didn't know he was building. It is using the MVC framework and is currently on a tfs server. So I have gotten it into the solution explorer. However I can't seem to get the references to update.

I have switched the package source between https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
and https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. The former will actually allow me the ability to try to install or upgrade but when I click it, it can't locate the server.

I have tried turning it off and on. I read somewhere that you have to delete the package on my computer and reinstall all of the references, but that is concerning. I am sure it is something simple...

Comment: _but that is concerning_ -- If you are using source control any changes can be immediately rolled back.

Comment: I am, but is that a logical fix?

Comment: did it compile and build on your local box before you applied your changes?  i.e. was it checked in reasonably to start with?   If you copy the original source prj files to a text file you will see hints to the version and locations of reference assemblies.

Comment: Have you try to right click solution in solution explorer, and then click "Enable NuGet Package Restore"? When you get a solution from TFS, it ignores the NuGet references dll. Not sure if this is your problem.

Comment: So removing all the packages and adding in a line in the package.config file to add in webgrease was the answer!